# IPhone connection to Xcode/Mac fails or is flapping

Tags: iphone, connection

I have very frequent issues with connecting my IPhone to the Mac and getting recognized by Xcode. Either the IPhone is not recognized at all on Mac or Xcode sees the device 2 sec then doesn't see it anymore and flapping this way endlessly. What I do to fix the issue is rebooting Iphone, closing and restarting Mac and disconnecting the IPhone and resetting the USB port with command -> sudo pkill usbmuxd. Sometimes it works but not always in this case I reboot the Mac as well and this process I do it every 3rd time I connect my Iphone. All versions are up to date: Mac, Xcode, Iphone. Do you have the same issues and idea to fix it. By the way I also bought a brand new USB cable but still the same problem.

Comment: Try plugging in the cable into a different port or cleaning the ports on both the device and the computer. Make sure you have a working cable to rule out the possibility of having a faulty cable.

Comment: Thanks but I checked the cable and his fine and that's why I bought a 2nd one to ensure it's not the cable but even with the new one the issue remains. I already changed USB ports as well without success.